# Disposing of Quranic text

Tags: quran, practical-islam, fiqh, sunni, hanafi

I had a few verses of the quran in my top jacket pocket, which I kept with me while I was doing some memorisation of the quran on the move.  i.e. because I didn't want to carry the full quran with me on the train, I bought a small booklet which contained some short verses from the local islamic shop.

I accidently left that booklet in my jacket and washed the jacket.  Now ihave a mash of paper, where about 10% of the text is readable and the rest is unreadable.

So my question is, how would I dispose of bearly readable quranic text like this?

Hanafi Sunni view prefered.

I've seen the 2 answers in this question:
[What does Qur'an or Hadith says regarding the correct methods of disposing the Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/196/disposing-old-unusable-quran-and-other-scriptures)

But the first answer doesn't use any authentic sources, and I find the second answer unclear.  Is the second answer saying that it should be buried or not, or should it be burned or not, or both or any?

Comment: just burn it...

Comment: This is a duplicate of the linked question. You should comment and ask for more information or offer a bounty.